# JSTL x:forEach comma-separated output

Tags: xml, jsp, foreach, jstl

I've got an xml file with the following contents:

```
<authors>
    <author>name 1</author>
    <author>name 2</author>
    <author>name 3</author>
</authors>
```

and I'd like to parse it with JSTL to a list like:

```
name1, name2, name3
```

and, if there are more than 3:

```
name1, name2, name3 et. al
```

I've got no problems using a `<x:forEach ..>` that puts out the names and to end at a specific author, but how to get the commas and check for the list length?

Comment: By any chance do you mean XSLT instead of JSTL?

Comment: @krock: no, it's the [JSTL XML taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html) You see this indeed very rarely because it's considered poor practice to parse XML in view side :) (like as with [JSTL SQL taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/tld-summary.html)). See also the JSTL info page when you hover the JSTL tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `varStatus` attribute in combination with `end` attribute. The `varStatus` refers to a local [`LoopTagStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) instance which offers several getter methods, such as [`getIndex()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getIndex%28%29) and [`isLast()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast%28%29). The `end` attribute specifies the index where the iteration should end.

```
<x:forEach select="..." var="author" varStatus="loop" end="3">
    <c:if test="${loop.index lt 3}">${author}</c:if>
    <c:if test="${loop.index lt 2 and not loop.last}">,</c:if>
    <c:if test="${loop.index eq 3}">et. al</c:if>
</x:forEach>
```